# How to make buddypress profile menu display username and user photo?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, buddypress

I am building a wordpress website and using buddypress plugin for community building.I added profile menu of buddypress from menu options in the dashboard.
Profile menu of buddypress only shows "profile" in the menu.How can i change the profile to show username and profile photo.

I can use `bp_loggedin_user_avatar('width='.bp_core_avatar_thumb_width(). '&height='.bp_core_avatar_thumb_height());`  for displaying buddypress profile photo and `$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->display_name;` for displaying username.

But i don't know where to use this code to change profile menu to display username and user photo.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set in dashboard-> appearance -> menu

Use below code in header.php,

```
    <?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();   ?>
<li class="profile-icon-sec">                                   
    <?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 38 ); ?>
    <span class="profile-name"><b>John Stephen</b> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/arrow-point-to-right.png" alt="" /></span>
</li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu avatar-dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-avatar-list"> <a  href="<?php echo home_url().'/members/'.$user->user_login; ?>/"> My Account</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-avatar-list"> <a  href=" <?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>"> Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<?php } else {?>
<li class="login-btn">
<a class="btn" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/login/">Login</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this inside buddypress plugin file?

Comment: Not understood your question, please explain briefly.

Comment: I meant,by default in Buddypress plugin,profile menu is given in dashboard-> appearance -> menu and is shown only when user is logged in.Is there any way to change that inside the buddypress plugin to show profile name and photo instead of just the "profile "?

Comment: That was a core functionality. We could not touch plugin folder directly, So I think this is good

Comment: Can this be implemented simply by using above code or should I change class, id according to the source?

Comment: You can use above code, I just used class and ID for designing.